# Soft key board hiding edit text

Tags: android, tabs, android-softkeyboard

In my application main screen is having tab host with four tabs at bottom.

RealTabContaint of the tabhost is  replace by relative fragments.

In one fragment there is another tabhost with two tabs at the top. One of the tab is associated with an Activity which layout consist of 4 textviews & one **List view**. When ever I tried to type in 3 rd & 4 th textviews the soft KeyBoards hide that Edittexts. User is not able to see what he is typing.

I tried :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

I am not able to put scroll view in main 4 Tabs screen as well as in activity layout. So, now I am hidding 1st & 2nd EditText when focus comes to 3 rd & 4 th editbox.

Its working but gives problem some time & I think this is a not good practice. I searched a lot & tried a lot but didnt finding any solution.

If any one is having solution Please....

Comment: Hope you are using a RelativeLayout in the layout where your 4 textbox and listview are added!

Comment: Arey you using android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen style?

Comment: No parent is Linear Layout and yes Theme.No.TitleBar. But after removing Theme no use..

Comment: No parent is Linear Layout then scroll view then in linear 4 edit text linear & scroll closed the one relative for custom dropdown its closed then list view & button & last parent linear closed. Yes Theme.No.TitleBar. But after removing Theme no use..

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. But the problem solved by using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

within the activity in Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

## call this function

```
       private void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText editText){
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null && getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText){
        InputMethodManager imm =       (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```